# What is the best way to modify .txt inside .zip before upload

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have web application where user log in his account and can download the program. The program is in zip and there is configuration file inside (.txt). 
What I want to do:

1. Take this zip/configuration file (.txt)
2. Change parameters inside configuration file
3. Send to user the whole zip with new configuration file

I know how to send zip to user, but what is the best way to modify file inside zip per user and send it, when there can be many users in the same time.

**EDIT**
How can I split it per user, for example, I have two users who in the same time click download, so my server should prepare two different zips for each user, but how can I do it. As mentioned by EJP bellow I can't modify zip, first I should unzip it, but where should I save temporary unziped files to be safe for each thread. Is there any best way to do it?

Comment: i would say: copy your text file to temporary file ->  modify copy-> zip up copy -> sent to user.

Comment: if you use `File.createTempFile`. it will create temporary file in system temp folder

Comment: @user902383 File.createTempFile I think it exactly what I'm looking for in this post. Thanks, could you answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is, create temporary file, by using `File.createTempFile`. Then copy content of your configuration file into your temporary file. Now you have thread safe copy of your file and you can modify it without any worries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to unzip, change, rezip, send. A ZIP file isn't a file system.

There is some kind of ZIP file system in Java 8 but under the hood it has to be doing the above.

Comment: How can I split it per user, for example, I have two users who in the same time click download, so my server should prepare two different zips for each user, but how can I do it, where should I save temporary unziped files. Is there any best way to do it?

Comment: You can store a static `AtomicInteger` or similar that you increment with each download, and keeps track of a filename/directory suffix. `/tmp/MyWebService/tempFiles1/`, `/tmp/MyWebService/tempFiles2/`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using the NIO FileSystem API you can (it will still do the re-zipping behind the scenes probably, but you don't have to worry about it):

```
Path zipPath = Paths.get("/path/to/file.zip");
FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null);
Path pathInZip = zipFS.getPath("/test.txt");

String s = Resources.toString(pathInZip.toUri().toURL(), Charsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(s);

Files.write(pathInZip, "Hello World!".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
zipFS.close();
```